# Display columns in matrix format using dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have the following table

[image]

I want to convert int into a matrix using python, to look something like below:

[image]

Can I get some direction as to where to start with this? I have used pandas to read two dataframes and merge them to create the initial table I have shown(one having two columns).

Code I am using is below is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyexcelerate import Workbook
import numpy as np
import time
start = time.process_time()
excel_file = 'Test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0, index_col=0)
print(df.columns)
print(df.index)

newdf= (df.pivot(index='ColumnB',columns='ColumnA', values='ColumnB'))
myNewDF = newdf.transform(lambda x: np.where(x.isnull(), '', 'yes'))
aftercalc = time.process_time()
print(aftercalc - start)

myNewDF.to_excel("1.xlsx")
print(time.process_time() - aftercalc)
```

The ouput of the prints are :

> Index(['ColumnB'], dtype='object') Index(['TypeA', 'TypeA', 'TypeA',
>   'TypeA', 'TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeB',
>          'TypeC', 'TypeC', 'TypeC', 'TypeD'],
>         dtype='object', name='ColumnA')

The error I get while running this is :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:_data\learn\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 2657, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'ColumnA'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 10, in
>   
>       newdf= (df.pivot(index='ColumnB',columns='ColumnA', values='ColumnB'))   File
>   "C:_data\learn\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 5628, in pivot
>       return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)   File
>   "C:_data\learn\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 379, in pivot
>       index = MultiIndex.from_arrays([index, data[columns]])   File "C:_data\learn\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2927, in **getitem**
>       indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   File "C:_data\learn\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 2659, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve?

```
newdf= (df.pivot(index='ColumnB',columns='ColumnA', values='ColumnB'))

newdf
Out[28]: 
ColumnA TypeA TypeB TypeC TypeD
ColumnB                        
A           A     A   NaN     A
B           B   NaN     B   NaN
C           C   NaN     C   NaN
D           D   NaN   NaN   NaN
E           E   NaN   NaN   NaN
F         NaN     F   NaN   NaN
Z         NaN   NaN     Z   NaN

newdf.transform(lambda x: np.where(x.isnull(), '', 'yes'))
Out[29]: 
ColumnA TypeA TypeB TypeC TypeD
ColumnB                        
A         yes   yes         yes
B         yes         yes      
C         yes         yes      
D         yes                  
E         yes                  
F               yes            
Z                     yes
```

Modified Code

```
import pandas as pd
#from pyexcelerate import Workbook
import time
import numpy as np
start = time.process_time()
excel_file = 'C:\\Users\\ss\\Desktop\\check.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0, index_col=0)
print(df.columns)
print(df.index)

newdf= (df.pivot(index='ColumnB',columns='ColumnA', values='ColumnB'))
myNewDF = newdf.transform(lambda x: np.where(x.isnull(), '', 'yes'))
aftercalc = time.process_time()
print(aftercalc - start)

myNewDF.to_excel("C:\\Users\\ss\\Desktop\\output.xlsx")
```

Comment: KeyError: 'ColumnA'

Comment: Check your dataframe column names? are there any spaces? or spelling issue?

Comment: There is definitely no spelling mistake. The only thing I am doing differently is , creating the `df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0, index_col=0)`

Comment: You are getting that error because your ColumnA is your dataframe's index. Please see the modified code i have added.

Comment: code updated as suggested but still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: apologies for being slightly slow learner. This works after I have created a new column with index values.

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
pd.crosstab(df.ColumnA,df.ColumnB).astype(bool)
```